# Create column to filter email domain

Tags: sql, email

I have a table like this

```
Table A
-------

Cust_Name   |   Email
___________________________________
Martin      |   martin@gmail.com
Hussey      |   hussey@yahoo.com
William     |   will@sfr.fr
```

And I want to add a column with the aim to filter by domain like this

```
Table A
-------

Cust_Name   |   Email Cust_Name   |   Email Domain
_____________________________________________________
Martin      |   martin@gmail.com  |      Gmail 
Hussey      |   hussey@yahoo.com  |      Yahoo
William     |   will@sfr.fr       |      SFR
```

How can I proceed via SQL (Sas Enterprise Guide)?

Comment: is your question how to add the column to the table?  or how to determine the email provider from the email address?  Not sure what you're asking for

Comment: Can you add some non-standard examples? Like `MyName@this.is.an.example.co.uk` or `MyName@This.is-an-even_odder.example.co.uk`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated field or a view using this:

```
DECLARE @Email VARCHAR(50) = 'Josh.Rubens@gmail.com'
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(@Email ,CHARINDEX('@',@Email ,1) + 1,LEN(@Email)), CHARINDEX('.', SUBSTRING(@Email ,CHARINDEX('@',@Email ,1),LEN(@Email)),1)  - 2) ;
```

Comment: Might be nice to have a short description what the code actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column and insert like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING('Email',CHARINDEX('@','Email',1)+1,CHARINDEX('.','Email',1)-1), 1,CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING('Email',CHARINDEX('@','Email',1)+1,CHARINDEX('.','Email',1)-1),1)-1),1,LEN(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING('Email',CHARINDEX('@','Email',1)+1,CHARINDEX('.','Email',1)-1),1,CHARINDEX('.',SUBSTRING('Email',CHARINDEX('@','Email',1)+1,CHARINDEX('.','Email',1)-1),1)-1)));
```

Comment: This will include the top-level domain extensions (`.com`, `.fr` etc). Looks like OP wants them cut off.

Comment: That would get the full domain e.g.gmail.com not just gmail

Comment: @BibinMatthew test it with a longer email address e.g. Hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Email, CHARINDEX('@', Email)+1, CHARINDEX('.',Email) - CHARINDEX('@', Email) + Len('.')-2)
```